# How to use docker in network bridge mode?

Tags: docker

I'm running Docker Quickstart Terminal on my Windows machine.

When Docker VM is set up to use Host-only Adapter (Default network settings) I get:

```
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

xxx@yyy MINGW64 ~
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED
     STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
a9cca0b96f48        my/server      "/bin/bash /start.sh"   About an hour a
go   Up 30 seconds       0.0.0.0:6083-6084->6083-6084/tcp   mycontainer
```

So far so good, but when Docker VM is set up to use Bridged Adapter I get:

```
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.5.92
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

XXX MINGW64 ~
$ docker ps
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://localhost:2375/v1.21/containers/
json: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp:
```

The way around it is to ssh to the Docker VM (192.168.5.92 in my case), however I loose access to my local machine from the terminal then.

Is there a way to point Docker Quickstart Terminal to the right IP of the Docker VM when using Bridged Adapter?